# Need advice on the flow of my AJAX form in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I need some help/guidance in how to write the AJAX piece of my application.

I have a button that when clicked will pop up a modal dialog. On the dialog I have an Ajax form which has a text box and a button to Save the values:

```
@using( Ajax.BeginForm("SaveText", new AjaxOptions{ OnSuccess = "ajaxSuccess" }) )
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Text)

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p> 
}
```

When the AJAX completes successfully I want to close the dialog and refresh a grid on my main page:

```
function ajaxSuccess() {
    closeDialog();
    refreshGrid();
}
```

I ran into problems when I tried to implement validation. I'm not really sure how to accomplish what I want. Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult SaveText(SaveTextViewModel model)
{
    if( ModelState.IsValid )
    {
        return PartialView("SaveTextPartial", model);
    }

    repository.SaveText(...);

    return PartialView("SaveTextPartial");
}
```

Here is where I'm having difficulty: when I submit the form and there are validation errors, the controller returns a partial view but the AJAX OnSuccess method completes. I don't know how to distinguish between a success with errors and a success without errors. When I have validation errors my form closes and my grid refreshes, which is not what I want.

Does anyone have any ideas? Do I need to restructure the entire flow of my AJAX call or do it completely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears like you don't need this form to work without Javascript (since you're always passing back a partial view), so why not, on success, pass back a simple JSON object?

```
return Json(new { success = true })
```

And if there's an error, return the partial view so you can replace the HTML.

Then test for it in your callback...

```
if (result.success) { }
```

That way, on success, you can close the dialog safely but on a validation error, you swap out the dialog's HTML with the HTML you received on the AJAX request.

I don't know what parameters are available for your onSuccess callback but I'm sure the response body is one of them.

Comment: Didn't realize I could return a PartialView in one path and a JsonReult in another path and the javascript would be able to make sense of it.

Comment: MVC is awesome that way ;) You can return HTML, JSON, XML, or plain text which can all be handled with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom HTTP header in case of error:

```
public ActionResult SaveText(SaveTextViewModel model)
{
    if( !ModelState.IsValid )
    {
        // a validation error occurred
        Response.AppendHeader("X-Error", "true");
        return PartialView("SaveTextPartial", model);
    }

    repository.SaveText(...);

    return PartialView("SaveTextPartial");
}
```

and on the client:

```
function ajaxSuccess(e, status, xhr) {
    if (xhr.getResponseHeader('X-ERROR')) {
        alert('failure');
    } else {
        alert('success');
    }
}
```

Comment: @bzlm, because if you send some status code other than 200, ajaxSuccess will never be invoked. But this could be solved by using the ajax complete I guess.

Comment: Yeah, why not? Success should mean success even for an HTTP-level observer. I'd turn on "detailed error messages" to avoid IIS high-jacking the error page, use HTTP 500 or similar for errors, and refresh the grid in `OnComplete`.